# Dummynet / ipfw error installing on Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, ipfw

The following error is returned when trying to install netipfw.inf to my network adapter:

> "Could not add the requested feature. The error is: 0xE000022F"

What does this mean, and how could I fix it? I am using the latest Dummynet Windows x64 binaries.

http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/

Comment: Those binaries are two years old (before Windows 10). Try building from source.

Comment: I have compiled Dummynet from the source, but I am now receiving, "the application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)." I have the latest .NET Framework, and DirectX installed.

Answer (score 1):

Install netipfw.inf after disabling signed driver enforcement.
 See [Windows 10: Disable Signed Driver Enforcement](http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/38289/~/windows-10%3A-disable-signed-driver-enforcement.)

```
Click the Start Start menu and select Settings.
Click Update and Security.
Click on Recovery.
Click Restart now under Advanced Startup.
Click Troubleshoot.
Click Advanced options.
Click Startup Settings.
Click on Restart.
On the Startup Settings screen press 7 or F7 to disable driver signature enforcement.
```

Comment: can you add some detail and why, etc

Comment: I able to install this driver but it does not appear in list of items,

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to a [compatibility problem for NDIS 5.x drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32640720/821134) on Win10. Since microsoft does not seem to fix this issue, instead someone would have to [update dummynet to NDIS 6](https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/webpagetest/issues/560#issuecomment-224125875).

Answer (score 0):

You may try [clumsy](https://github.com/jagt/clumsy) instead of dummynet. I used it to increase latency - works great.